# Divisor Pattern - Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

List all positive divisors of
$18
$

List all positive divisors of $75
$

Find another number with the same number of divisors. What is the pattern?

$18 – 1,2,3,6,9,18
$

$75 – 1,3,5,25,75
$

$99 – 1, 3, 9, 11, 33, 99
$

But I really can't see a pattern here unless its something very basic.

Comment: Consider numbers of the form $p^2q$. They all have $6$ divisors.

Comment: I believe you're missing a factor of 75: 15.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with exactly 6 divisors are either of the form $p^2 q$ or $p^5$, where $p$ and $q$ are both primes and $p \neq q$.

In the former case, the divisors are 1, $p$, $q$, $p^2$, $pq$ and $p^2 q$.

In the latter case, the divisors are 1, $p$, $p^2$, $p^3$, $p^4$ and $p^5$.

This page should help you generalize it to other values of $\sigma_0(n)$: http://oeis.org/wiki/Index_entries_for_number_of_divisors

Answer (score 1):

Consider the exponents in their prime factorizations, and how these relate to divisors.

Comment: Yes I can now see that all divisors that are prime appear in the prime factorization of that particular number.

Comment: @CharlesEpp That's obviously true of any number, and is not a property of the *specific exponents* of the prime in $n$'s factorization. lhf has already spoiled the answer for you in the comments above.

Comment: That's assuming numbers like 32 and 243 don't count for this. You know Yoda wound up on Dagobah, but do you know when or how he went there?

Comment: @Robert Given the three examples and the way the problem speaks of "the pattern," it's no assumption that fifth powers of primes are not the subject of the question. There's no problem with going above and beyond, though.

Comment: @blue Maybe you're right. But Charles did write "Find another number with the same number of divisors" and he didn't write anything like $\omega(n) > 2$.

Comment: @Robert I think it's plain and clear what the question is.

Comment: Why would I point it out if you didn't go above and beyond the question?

Comment: Because if I was the one who left it out, it would suddenly become "an inexcusable omission of an essential fact" rather than just something extra no one cares about.

Comment: Okay, if you say so.